# Newtonsoft Json cant get inherited type

Tags: c#, json, .net

I already searched this problem here but culd not find any working solution.
I have some JSON file that have type metadata like this

```
"@odata.type": "#SomeType"
```

This `SomeType` is inherited from `SomeTypeBase`. I'm only getting base type when json is deserialized. Why? I tried `TypeNameHandling.All` but doesnt work.

Maybe is probem with this `@odata.type`?

I forgot to mention, it's a .net 7 project

**UPDATE**

Here's some code:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string serialized)
    {
        try
        {
            using var reader = new StringReader(serialized);
            using var reader2 = new JsonTextReader(reader)
            {
                DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
                FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal,
            };
            return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

Serializer is static:

```
public static readonly JsonSerializer Serializer = new()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
        FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal,
    };
```

Comment: Can you add some code

Comment: Do you have values in props which are added on base class or they are null? What serialization uses for null handling - are nulls returned?

Comment: @Hervé I've uploaded it

Comment: @SreckoRistic there are values, not nulls

Comment: AFAIK Newtonsoft json needs the type to be defined in a field called `$type`, like `"$type": "SomeType"`. You will need to use some custom converter. Take a look a [this library](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes).

Comment: @Alberto I've changed @ odata.type to $type in JSON but now I'm getting exception that cannot resolve that type in $type property

Comment: @milandjukic88 Have you specified the type fullname? Like: `Some.Namespace.TypeName, Some.Assembly.Name`